# How to use the Dictionary Key in a ComboBox instead of Value

Tags: c#, dictionary, combobox

I Have a static Dictionary that I use as ItemsSource of a Combobox:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Country> Countries => new Dictionary<string, Country>()
{
   { "CY", new Country( "CY", "Cyprus" ), ... },
   { "B", new Country( "B", "Belgium", ... ) },
   ...
   etc
```

The Key would be like "CY" and the Value is a Country that has some properties, amongst which is a FullName ("Cyprus") 
and a ShortName like "CY" (also used as Key)

the ComboBox goes like:

```
<ComboBox
   x:Name="CountryCb"
   DisplayMemberPath="Value.ShortName"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static cf:Configuration.Instance}, Path=Countries}" 
   SelectedValuePath="Value"
   SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCountry , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The Property SelectedCountry has Type Country and must be set, choosing some item from the ComboBox's pull-down.

This works well: SelectedCountry's setter is accessed and set.

Now the problematic one:
I have another  static Dictionary

```
public static Dictionary<int, CBListItem> SectionTypeList => new Dictionary<int, CBListItem>()
  {
      { 27, new CBListItem( "...", "...", "..." ) },
      ...
      etc
```

which is a list of Section type data.

CBListItem has properties like FullName and ShortName, which are strings.

I want to use the Dictionary's Key (an int, 27) to set the Section's property 
SectionType via a ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox
   x:Name="SectionsCb"
   DisplayMemberPath="Value.FullName"
   ItemsSource="{x:Static vm:MainViewModel.SectionTypeList}"
   SelectedValuePath="Key"
   SelectedValue="{Binding SectionType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The display works well (FullName shows), but not the setting of SectionType (an int).
Choosing another option in the ComboBox pull-down does not access the 
SectionType setter (as a breakpoint shows).
"Key" does not work,  for some reason.

Question: how can I get this second ComboBox to work like the first one?

Comment: How does `SectionType` look like?

Comment: edited original: it's an int

Comment: I've written a small example with binding the same dictionary to combobox, and unable to reproduce your problem. Could you please share a reproducible sample and used .NET version

Comment: Do you have a property on the view model for the section? If so, you should use `SelectedValue={Binding Section.SectionType, ....}` instead of directly setting the SectionType?

Comment: I implemented a work-around: I changed CBListItem to contain the Key value too.